# Android Record Audio NO SDCARD

Tags: android, audio, sd-card, audio-recording

Im reading about how to record audio in android and i want to know if is possible to record audio without store it in SD Card. What happend with terminals that dont have sd card?
Also, in my application, i only want to record a sound and upload to my server... so maybe is not necessary to record in sd o internal memory.

I need to take a photo, write a text and record audio in the same activity to send three to my server and store in a DB to use it in other terminal.

Someone knows something about??

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can store you files in context.getCacheDir()

Comment: thank you so much, i try to do it
if someone has one example, there will be nice ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
         String fileName = "test.3gp"; 
        MediaRecorder mRecorder = mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);        
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath + "/" + fileName);
```

standart path is /data/data/YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME/cache/ Also you need ensure that you have enough internal storage space